# qgis2web- do not show as map project

Tags: qgis2web, offset

I have a layer with features overlapped with each other. To show them in my map, I put value in the offset (layer properties) so I can see the overlapped lines. However when I used the qgis2web and export the map into the web, it does not show how exactly I see them in the map. The offset lines is still not offset in the web view.

[image: Pic1BeforeExport## Heading ##]

Result after exporting:

[image: Pic2AfterExport]

My question: How to have the same view/ output in the web as in my map?

Comment: qgis2web only supports a subset of the styling options. You will have to create actual shifted geometries I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but can u walk me through that process?